# Issue with Custom Authentication Background and Custom Login Form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-login

I am working on a django app where I have to authenticate users from active directory.
I can do it with following code in CustomAuthenticationBackend:

```
    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
    
    username = kwargs['username']
    password = kwargs['password']
    # type = kwargs['userType']
    adConnect,message = self.is_valid_ad(username, password)
    
    if adConnect:
        request.session['pss'] = password
        try:
            userExist = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
            if userExist.check_password(password) is True:
                return userExist
            else:
                pass
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # raise ValidationError(username+" is not allowed to access this application.")
            return self.createNewUserFromAD(adConnect, username, password)
    else:
        pass
```

and in settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'dcw_app.CustomBackendAuth.CustomBackendAuth',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

and in urls:

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='dcw_app/login.html'), name='login'),
```

Problem comes when I need to add an extra field in login form. Authentication does not happen and on submit form is just reloaded. Custom form is like this in forms.py:

```
class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    errors = {
        'required': 'Admin Must enter at least one role.',
    }
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        

    userType = forms.ChoiceField(error_messages=errors,required=True, 
                                 label=pgettext("field label","Role"),widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'userType'}), choices=UserModal.USER_ROLES,)
```

and in urls.py

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='dcw_app/login.html',authentication_form=UserLoginForm), name='login'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this role serve as a condition for the difference in content served by the server?
If so, you could try something like this:

```
def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):

username = kwargs['username']
password = kwargs['password']
# type = kwargs['userType']
adConnect,message = self.is_valid_ad(username, password)

if adConnect:
    request.session['pss'] = password
    try:
        userExist = User.objects.get(username__iexact=username)
        if userExist.check_password(password) is True:
            if userType is "foo":
                #do something 1
            else if userType is "bar":
                #do something 2
        else:
            pass
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # raise ValidationError(username+" is not allowed to access this application.")
        return self.createNewUserFromAD(adConnect, username, password)
else:
    pass
```

Another method is to create account types in the database itself and use the type to serve using the same condition

Comment: Yes, it does serve different content based on role type.I want to have an option in login form to select roles (Role1 or Role2) which loggin in to the application. When I add that in Form, the custom authentication code doesn't work and nothing happens.

Comment: Try adding a role condition in your custom view, and do make sure, that your view is being used and not the one of the allauth, which may be the cause of concern, since, in your URLs, you have taken views.authviews()

Comment: with views.authviews() in urls, if I add authentication_form=UserLoginForm to use custom form instead of basic username password form, then only it fails.

Comment: This indicates your allauth login and authentication code is being used

Comment: Here is what I want to accomplish:
1 - Take user role in Login Form.
2 - Authenticate User with Active Directory and show view based on provided role.


Any idea how to achieve this. I am new in Django